# Thumbnail now showing in django admin list view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have created a basic file upload app and i'd like to be able to view a thumbnail of the image on the django admin list view. I've tried implementing the code on this blog post - http://www.acedevs.com/blog/2011/07/11/django-admin-list-view-thumbnails/ ).

After adding the code, i've got the extra field called 'slide thumbnail' but when i upload an image it just sais 'none' so it's converting then image to a thumbnail and displaying it.

I don't have any errors so not sure exactly where i'm going wrong..

Here is my code and hopfully someone can shed some light.

MODLES:

from django.db import models
from sorl.thumbnail.main import DjangoThumbnail
import os

```
class File(models.Model):


    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('Image', 'Image'),
        ('Document', 'Document')
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=400, help_text="Enter the title of the file, this will appear on the listings page")




    file_type = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, help_text="Optional, but will help with filtering on listings page.", max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default=None)


    image_upload = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/filesApp", height_field="image_height", width_field="image_width", blank=True, null=True)

    file_upload = models.FileField(upload_to="pdf/filesApp", blank=True, null=True)

    image_height = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)

    image_width = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)



    def slide_thumbnail(self, width=300, height=200):
        if self.image:
            thumb = DjangoThumbnail(self.image, (width, height))
            return '{img src="%s" /}' % thumb.absolute_url
        return '{img src="/media/img/admin/icon-no.gif" alt="False"}'
    slide_thumbnail.allow_tags = True
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Slide: %s - %sx%s' % (self.title, self.image_height, self.image_width)
```

ADMIN.PY

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import *


def delete_selected(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for element in queryset:
        element.delete()
delete_selected.short_description = "Delete selected elements"

class FileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = File
    actions = [delete_selected]

    list_display = ('title', 'file_type', 'slide_thumbnail')

admin.site.register(File, FileAdmin)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the variable was wrong in my function that was creating the thumbnail. Anyway, here is my finished code if anyone is interested in using thumbnails in the django admin list view.

models.py

from django.db import models
from sorl.thumbnail.main import DjangoThumbnail
import os

class File(models.Model):

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('Image', 'Image'),
    ('Document', 'Document')
)

title = models.CharField(max_length=400, help_text="Enter the title of the file, this will appear on the listings page")




file_type = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, help_text="Optional, but will help with filtering on listings page.", max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default=None)


image_upload = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/filesApp", height_field="image_height", width_field="image_width", blank=True, null=True)

file_upload = models.FileField(upload_to="pdf/filesApp", blank=True, null=True)

image_height = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)

image_width = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)



def slide_thumbnail(self, width=300, height=200):
    if self.image_upload:
        thumb = DjangoThumbnail(self.image_upload, (width, height))
        return '<img src="%s" />' % thumb.absolute_url
    return '{img src="/media/img/admin/icon-no.gif" alt="False"}'
slide_thumbnail.allow_tags = True

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'File: %s - %sx%s' % (self.title, self.image_height, self.image_width)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import *


def delete_selected(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for element in queryset:
        element.delete()
delete_selected.short_description = "Delete selected elements"

class FileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = File
    actions = [delete_selected]

    list_display = ('title', 'file_type', 'slide_thumbnail')

admin.site.register(File, FileAdmin)
```

Please note: You will need sorl-thumbnail installed.

Hope this saves anyone the pain i had to go through!

Answer (score 0):

The `TypeError` is because of using `FileField`. [`ImageField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) is defined as

```
class ImageField(upload_to=None[, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100, **options])
```

while [`FileField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield) is defined as

```
class FileField(upload_to=None[, max_length=100, **options])
```

Comment: Is it possible for me to do what I want with FileField?

Comment: I've removed the height_field, width_field & as the FileField does not support them like you mentioned. I'm now getting this error - Exception Value:  

FileAdmin.list_display[1], 'file_type, slide_thumbnail' is not a callable or an attribute of 'FileAdmin' or found in the model 'File'.

Comment: Directly generating the preview from a FileField will not work. However, you can generate the preview image of the uploaded file(for pdfs) separately and store it in ImageField and then use that ImageField while showing the thumbnails

Comment: Ok, so do you mean keep the FileField, upload the FileField as normal then transfer the file into an ImageField, then generate the Image from there? would it cause any problems if the file was anything other than an Image?

Comment: I don mean transfer of file to an image. I am suggesting an extra ImageField for the preview purposes. For example, a preview of the pdf file is mostly a snapshot of the pdf at some point. The intended preview or the snapshot can be saved as a previewfile (which could be an imageField) to be used while showing thumbnails. Just my ideas!

Comment: With respect to ur exception, please remove the single quotes around 'file_type, slide_thumbnail' and try 'file_type', 'slide_thumbnail'

Comment: Ah yeah thanks, that's removed the error I had. I can now view the files on the admins view listing page. I now have a column that sais 'Slide thumbnail' but when i click into the file or entry in the DB i get 'Exception Value:  

not enough arguments for format string'